# How to resolve XStartTimeoutError: Failed to start X on display ":1013" error

Tags: python-3.x, x11, pyvirtualdisplay

I want to run a pyvirtualdisplay on my Mac.

After installing all dependencies I installed X11 because
i needed  Xvfb to run and changed some permission for some folder called ~/.Xauthority to 777.

Still, if I ran

```py
display = pyvirtualdisplay.Display(visible=0, size=(320, 240)).start()

XStartTimeoutError: Failed to start X on display ":1013" (xdpyinfo check failed).
```

What I also tryed was to change 
X11Forwarding in my /etc/ssh/sshd_config file to yes. 
Did not work out.

How can I resolve the issue?

Constructive help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this same error while trying to run Selenium using PyVirtualDisplay on my Raspberry Pi. I was not running Xephyr.

In a separate terminal window I ran

```
export DISPLAY=:0 XAUTHORITY=/etc/X11/host-Xauthority
```

and then

```
Xephyr :1 -fullscreen
```

Then re ran my python script and it worked.

If that doesn't work for you, here is where the actual error is occurring in the PyVirtualDisplay package: https://github.com/ponty/PyVirtualDisplay/blob/d229fcf892fdda17887684b977365d1fa90255eb/pyvirtualdisplay/abstractdisplay.py#L149

As you can see, you might need to install `xdpyinfo` in some form on your Mac.